# How to change mark properties with selections [vega-lite]

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, altair

How can one change *mark properties* (not field encodings or values) with vega-lite selections ?

For example, to highlight selected bars with a layer mark {type: bar, fill: none, stroke, black}.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer in the [interactive bar select highlight example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_bar_select_highlight.html)

It may not be directly possible to change mark properties via selection but one can conditionally set `fillOpacity` and `strockWidth` encodings channel with a selection.

Releveant piece of code is :

```
 "fillOpacity": {
      "condition": {"selection": "select", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.3
    },
    "strokeWidth": {
      "condition": [
        {
          "test": {
            "and": [
              {"selection": "select"},
              "length(data(\"select_store\"))"
            ]
          },
          "value": 2
        },
        {"selection": "highlight", "value": 1}
      ],
      "value": 0
    }
```